# Get child count using hibernate in springmvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

If we are creating a backend for website. We will obviously create categories and posts/products. To add/edit/delete categories we will obviously create a table like structure. for example:[This is category listing as table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHUOa.png)

Category would have a child category in a same table, number of child category could be 1 - many. I would like to show the number of child category as i have mentioned in above image.

As a CI developer i use to do that by using Query in the view,

> Here is the example

```
<?php 
            if(sizeof($results)>0)
                {     
                $i=1;

                foreach($results as $key => $list)
                  {


                  if($i%2==0)$cls="row1"; else $cls="row2";   
            ?>       
            <tr id="<?php echo $list->id;?>" class="<?php echo $cls; ?>">    
                <td> <?php echo $list->title, anchor("admin/categories/update/".$list->id."/", '<i class="fa fa-pencil rtrt"></i>' ); ?></td>

                <td> 

                     <?php 
                        // it will return number of childs
                         echo anchor ('admin/categories/category/'.$list->id, $this->Common->select_child ('tbl_category', $list->id) );
                     ?>
                </td>
```

Right now i am using Spring-mvc, hibernate, Jpa, and Mysql DB. I am known that doing sql query from a jsp would be a bad practice.

Here is my Jsp Code for table like structure,

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
         <th><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></th>
         <th>Category Name</th>
         <th>Child</th>
         <th>Created</th>
         <th>Updated</th>
         <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:if test="${not empty category}">
          <c:forEach var="cat" items="${category}">
            <tr>
                 <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/${cat.id}/edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
                 <td>${cat.title}</td>
                 <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/show/${cat.id}"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></a></td>
                 <td>${cat.created}</td>
                 <td>${cat.updated}</td>
                 <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
```

> Here is the category POjo class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Categories {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private Long parent_id;

private String title;

private String url_title;

private String description;

private String created;

private String updated;

/* 
 * @ At the time of Creating new user
 * Auto persist created date
 * Auto persist updated for first time
 */
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate (){

    // Date conversion to string
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:s");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    String now = sdf.format(date);

    created = now;
    updated = now;


}


/*
 *  Respective Getter and Setter Methods
 *  
 */
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getParent_id() {
    return parent_id;
}public void setParent_id(Long parent_id) {
    this.parent_id = parent_id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getUrl_title() {
    return url_title;
}public void setUrl_title(String url_title) {
    this.url_title = url_title;
}

public String getCreated() {
    return created;
}public void setCreated(String created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public String getUpdated() {
    return updated;
}public void setUpdated(String updated) {
    this.updated = updated;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Categories other = (Categories) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

> The Question is

how can i get children count without doing sql query from Jsp ?
Please Help me i need a suggestion.

Comment: can you add the categorie entity pleaz ?

Comment: I just added the categories class ? can you please Suggest me, how to achieve what i need.

Comment: I v posted an answer, but I dont know what you realy mean by : **children count**

Comment: consider an example of clothing site category which will hold value like (mens wear, childrens wear, womens wear ) and there children will be tshirt, jeans, shirt.

Comment: so mens wear will have 3 children (tshirt, jeans and shirt) and the womens wear will have its own children, so i want to count that kind of children in table view of category.

Comment: you will have to associate your category to childCategories first

Comment: can you provide me a hint or some links how to do it, or example code

Comment: Like this : `@OneToMany private List<Categories> subCategories;`

Answer (score 0):

to get a List count on jsp side use jstl functions like below :

declare the taglibe of jstl.functions

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

then you can try this

```
<c:set var="count" value="${fn:length(you_array)}" />
```

this will create a variable `"count"` taking as value : `you_array.size()`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help someone like me,

> Modified entity class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private Long parent_id;
private String title;
private String url_title;
private String description;
private Long status;
private String created;
private String updated;

@ManyToOne 
@JoinColumn(
name="parent_id", 
insertable=false, 
updatable=false) 
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Categories parentCategory;

@OneToMany(
fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
mappedBy="parentCategory", 
cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, 
orphanRemoval=true )

private Set<Categories> child = new HashSet<Categories>();
```

Since i am new to Jpa/orm/hibernate/spring when i posted this question i did not knew about entity relationship which we can manage in hibernate. I did some research and found out about hibernate **'Uni/Bi directional'** association using **annotation** like (**one to many, many to one, many to many**). I suggest if you are new to JPA and hibernate then please visit  [This link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html) before wasting your time.

> What I have done

**Bidirectional associations with join :** using @ManyToOne @Onetomany @joinColumn

**Solve Notfound exception using @NotFound(NotFoundAction.IGNORE)**
I have a categories (eg. Base category) which wont have any parent category so its 'parent_id' will be 0 in database but Hibernate will throw exception while querying records from database with id 0, after a successfull association.

**Used insertable/updatable = false :** set this properties to false if you are inserting and updating only one category at a time.

**Used "cascade=cascadetype.remove" "orphanremoval=true" :** set this properties, if you want to delete child categories when you delete parent category. When you invoke your serviceImplementation.delete(category cat) method, if "cat:object" is parent for other categories hibernate will automatically delete it's children categories before deleting cat:object itself.

> At last the Answer for my question

After the successful association with annotation, when you will query category rows from database. If it's a parent category for other categories hibernate will add **"child Collection"** in your object like this.

```
03:20:16.490 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG
o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter -
com.pack.librarymanagementsystem.model.Categories
{created=2016-06-10 7:45:32, parent_id=38, url_title=Bhm 5th sem, 
description=<p>asd</p>,
parentCategory=com.pack.librarymanagementsystem.model.Categories#38,
id=43, title=Bhm 5th sem, updated=2016-06-10 7:45:32, child=[], status=1}
```

Check It in your console log if you are using eclipse. The child collection hibernate just added wont have any data. Hibernate will store only proxys.

> The solution is to get the size of a child collection.

If you will do **isEmpty()** check on that child collection the result will be true. Thats where the **"fetch = FetchType.EAGER"** Kicks in. By default fetchtype is set to lazy. After changing fetchtype to eager hibernate will add objects as a child instead of adding proxy.

If you will do **isEmpty** check on that child collection now, the result will be false. Which means we can get the size of a collection.

> This is the jsp

```
<c:if test="${not empty category}">
<c:forEach var="cat" items="${category}">
<tr>
    <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/${cat.id}/edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
    <td>${cat.title}</td>
    <td>
        // Child count
        <c:if test="${not empty cat.child}" >
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/show/${cat.id}">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> ${ fn:length(cat.child)}
            </a>    
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty cat.child}" >
            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> 0
        </c:if>
    </td>
    <td>${cat.created}</td>
    <td>${cat.updated}</td>
    <td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${cat.status == 1}">Published</c:when>
            <c:otherwise>Unpublished</c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="ids[]" value="${cat.id}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

> And this is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/show/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewCategory( Map<String, Object> model) {

List<Categories> category = categoryService.getAllCategoriesByParent(Id); 
model.put("category",category);

return "category/view";
}
```

I hope this would help someone on saving his/her time.
Thank you